# What is the most commonly used line length limit in actual applications?

Tags: lint

Not sure if this is best place to ask this, but there are many style guides out there that propose line length limits, many as low as 80 characters. What is the most commonly used line length limit in actual applications? Is going as low as 80 actually feasible?

Comment: Are we talking like all languages here?

Comment: Yeah, any programming language really, although I mainly work in web languages.

Comment: https://github.com/google/styleguide/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=line+length&type=

Comment: Going back to classic standards, punched cards had 80 or 96 characters, while line printers were 80, 120, or 132 columns. 80 and 120 were the most commonly used record sizes.

Comment: Classic windows max_path length is 260 characters, but that includes the zero terminator. With Unicode NTFS file systems the length can be longer, but Windows Explorer is apparently still limited to 260 characters.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your/your teams preferences. Some of the arguments for the 80 character line are:

- You can fit multiple editors side by side with shorter lines.
- 80 characters forces you to write more concise code so

  ```
  // Looks to confusing to some people
  if ((browser.OS == 'win') && (browser.userAgent == 'IE')) {

  // More concise
  isIE = (browser.userAgent == 'IE');
  isWindows = (browser.OS == 'win');
  if (isIE && isWindows) {
  ```
- Historic reasons (The IBM 
  punch card had 80 columns, as well as old style terminals.

Arguments for more than 80 characters (I have mine set to 150):

- We now have larger monitors, so why bother
- Long expressions are grouped together instead of being broken up, easier to read to some people (myself included)

You also have to consider that you code may be reviewed, emailed, debugged and rewritten by people that aren't you. I happen to write code on my own most of the time, but I do have my own standards. As long as you write consistent, readable code, you won't have a problem with line lengths. But whatever you do, please don't write anything longer than 150 (and I'll admit, I'm pushing the limit on that) it's just ugly and can definitely be broken up.